# Post request Axios : Network error

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm using NodeJS for the backend, and ReactJS for the frontend.

I've a problem with request Axios network. All my Get request work. But Post request don't work. I have just this error "network error"

I created a simple webservice to show you my problem :

```
//Serveur code

helloWs : (request:Express.Request, response:Express.Response) => {
        try {
            response.send('hello WS !')
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            response.send('error' + error + 'status : ' + error.response.status)     
            response.end()    
        }
    }

//Here I create my root 
router.post('/helloWs',DocumentController.helloWs)

//This is my front

 axios.post('http://localhost:9000/1/documents/helloWs', { 
 }) .catch(function (error) {
                if (error.response) {
                    console.log('Error data : ', error.response.data);
                    console.log('Error status : ', error.response.status);
                    console.log('Error headers : ', error.response.headers);
                } else if (error.request) {
                    console.log('Error request : ', error.request);
                } else {
                    console.log('Error message : ', error.message);
                }
                console.log(error.config);
            })
```

In the navigator console, I've just `network error` , and my webservice is in OPTION and not in "POST"

I'm trying to add header in axios, but it doesn't work. I specify that I've tested with postman, and it's okay.
Do you have an idea ?
Thank you

Comment: It might be a CORS issue. Does your server accept cross origin requests?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, But here the interesting part is, was able to see the response in the browser network tab, In the middle response, got overriding or changed to `Network error` by axios, not sure why, and also seeing the CORS error in the browser. By setting up in the cors in the server, It got resolved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is most likely a cors related error, the OPTION request is made by the browser before the actual request to check if your domain has the rights to access the resource.

Postman doesn't do the preflight request that's why you get the response

try adding this middleware in your server side code before defining the routes

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this bug occurring with my setup. For some reason, prepending the POST request with http:// (this is a dev server on localhost) enabled the network once again.

I haven't dug into the axios docs, but I am guessing there is some code that automatically prepends GET requests with http:// but fails to do so for POST methods? That's one possibility to explain this odd behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your react-native app on an android emulator, this might work:

Run this in powershell or cmd:
adb reverse tcp:9000 tcp:9000

This will make your android emulator reach localhost at port 9000.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error that was near-impossible to debug. It ended up being that my backend wasn't https whereas my frontend was. Fixed it by making my backend https and I no longer get the error!