# React: Axios Error "Error: Network Error", My react app cannot receive axios.post response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I hava Nodejs Express Backend, React Frontend.
I checked if frontend sends a request to the backend and that request is sent to backend.
And the backend sends a response to the frontend but cannot receive.

1. Frontend -- request --> Backend **checked. and the request reaches the backend.**
2. Frontend <-- response -- Backend

During the second process, **if I receive using postman, it works well.**
But if I receive using frontend, it is not working and just throw the error "Error: Network error", anymore information isn't provided.

Also I tried [React: Axios Network Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980173/react-axios-network-error) and
[Post request Axios : Network error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132636/post-request-axios-network-error).

Node js Backend:

```
export const Login = async (req: Request, res: Response, next:NextFunction) => {
        console.log("LOGIN SUCCESS");
        res.json({ code: 200, token: "token" });
}
```

React Frontend:

```
const Login = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:6382/auth/login', { id: "id", password: "password" }); // ERROR!
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err); // Displays "Error: Network error"
    }
```

Additionally, My backend
app.js

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as cors from 'cors'
import * as helmet from 'helmet';

class App {
    public app: express.Express;

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.initializeMiddlewares();
    }
    
    private initializeMiddlewares() {
        this.app.use(helmet());
        this.app.use(cors());
        this.app.use(express.json({limit:"100mb"}));
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({limit:"100mb", extended:true}));
    }
}

export default App;
```

server.ts

```
import App from './app';

const { app } = new App;

app.listen(6382 ,() => {
  console.log(
    `Server listening on : 6382`);
});
```

What should I do?

Comment: /auth/login
May be this is not the full url. host name is missing.

Comment: sorry. same result. and I checked my request reaches backend before.

Comment: can you add full backend code including middleware?

Comment: @AselaPriyadarshana OK

Comment: In which port are you running your FE?

Comment: @Dez FE port is 3000

Comment: Still I cannot solve this.

Comment: Change `const { app } = new App;` to `const app = new App;`. You didn't provide a named, export, so app is the default one.

Answer (score 1):

Previously had the same issue, I forgot to add proxy to package.json. You have to add it to package.json at front-end files and it should do the trick.

```
"proxy": your backend url..
```

Comment: I add `"proxy": "http://localhost:6382/"` but new error thrown "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed: WebSocket is closed due to suspension."

Comment: And "Error: Network error" still continues to occur.

Comment: Have you tried to add these 2 properties to cors? cors({origin: true, credentials: true})

Comment: The error has disappeared, but Network error still occurs.